# simplify search for html element in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking for html elements in a string.  This works but I have a ton of html elements to check and for various strings. Can this be simplified so I can check all common html element types?

```
    $("<div/>").html(test_string).find('a').each(function (idx, elm) {
        //here are your anchors
        test_string = "error saving test string. can't contain html elements.";
    });

    $("<div/>").html(test_string).find('img').each(function (idx, elm) {
        test_string = "error saving test string. can't contain html elements.";
    });

    $("<div/>").html(test_string).find('input').each(function (idx, elm) {
        test_string = "error saving test string. can't contain html elements.";
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create just one element, populate its HTML, and then use the selector string `a, img, input`, and check the `.length` of the resulting collection:

```js
let test_string = 'foo <input> bar';

const $div = $("<div/>").html(test_string);
if ($div.find('a, img, input').length) {
    test_string = "error saving test string. can't contain html elements.";
    console.log("error saving test string. can't contain html elements.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create div and add string to it and just check if it contains any child element, this way you don't need to put check of every type of html tags / element

```
var $div = $("<div/>").html(test_string);
if($div.children().length>0) {
        //here are your anchors
        test_string = "error saving test string. can't contain html elements.";
  );
```